# Monitor Windows Events (e.g. MSSQLServer) in Azure?

Tags: windows, azure, events, logging, azure-virtual-machine

I searched for about one week for the oppurtunity to monitor different windows events, for example the SQL-event(or service) in AzureRM virtual machines.
I tried it with different LogAnalytics queries, Runbooks, Powershell scripts to connect to the vm, etc. But everything I tried doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestions?

The solution should inform me, when a windows service stopped.

Best regards!

Comment: Did that help? Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Monitor, which now includes Log Analytics and Application Insights, provides sophisticated tools for collecting and analyzing telemetry that allow you to maximize the performance and availability of your cloud and on-premises resources and applications. It helps you understand how your applications are performing and proactively identifies issues affecting them and the resources they depend on.

Activity log alerts are the alerts that get activated when a new activity log event occurs that matches the conditions specified in the alert. You can follow the following document to set an activity log alert: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/alert-activity-log?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json